Do purchased from the Well of Charon count towards Obol Points?
Obol Points are earned after you spend a certain amount of Gold Crowns at Charon's shop. Does money spent at a Well of Charon count towards earning Obol Points?

Yes, Well of Charon purchases count towards earning Obol Points. I confirmed by checking the Indulgences menu (D-Pad Left, L1/R1 to switch tabs) before and after a purchase to see how many more Coins I needed to spend to get the next Obol Point.

